# How does jQuery relate to functional programming?

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming

Using jQuery helps in functional programming? I am using jQuery and want to do functional programming after some time. So, just need to know about it.

I went to google and found this http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/jquery-is-a-monad/
and this 
http://www.windley.com/archives/2009/01/jquery_monads_and_functional_programming.shtml

Comment: jQuery does not relate to functional programming at all.

Comment: what about articles like this one http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/jquery-is-a-monad/

Comment: And the support article for original one http://www.windley.com/archives/2009/01/jquery_monads_and_functional_programming.shtml

Comment: By "functional", are you referring to methods like `each()` and `map()` we use instead of loops?

Comment: I think it's polite to explain the to OP why the question was closed.  While the topic might solicit extended discussion, I can't imagine how it is otherwise "not constructive".  jQuery certainly has influences from functional programming, both in its internals and its API.  The methods each() and map() are classic higher order programming methods.  It might be more useful for someone to acknowledge this and then refer the OP to [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) or [functional.js](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)

Comment: This question should be moved to the [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). It's basically an offshoot of [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/25586/98428).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery I believe has little to do with it. Its purpose is to help in webpage programming, not enhance functional programming.

Rather in Javascript itself it is possible to do functional programming, if you so choose. I advise to look up information about functional programming in Javascript, instead of adding jQuery into the mix.

Comment: Would love to know your view on this: 
"So, if you’re a jQuery programmer you may be moving more and more toward a functional style of programming without even knowing it." 

http://www.windley.com/archives/2009/01/jquery_monads_and_functional_programming.shtml

Comment: So? jQuery is a **library**. It neither enables or hinders functional programming in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is only a library for JavaScript.

JavaScript support any kind of structural type you want (No classes\OOP\etc.)